# How to change width and height of Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change `Column`'s width and height, but it seem's that `Column` have no property `width` or `height`.

Is there any way to change height or width of Column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap column inside  container and provide width and height.

Comment: Instead of a Container widget, I recommend the SizedBox widget because it is lightweight than a container.